# Angular2, Loading modules with less server calls

Tags: optimization, angular, systemjs, node-modules

'import {ComponentHere} from "angular2"', this one hits the server with so may calls for getting all the required file. Is there any way to decrease the number of calls to server?

//localhost:9739/node_modules/@angular/common/src/directives/core_directives.js.
//localhost:9739/node_modules/@angular/common/src/pipes/uppercase_pipe.js".
//localhost:9739/node_modules/@angular/common/src/forms/directives/control_container.js".
etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using a WebPack (https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/webpack.html) it normally will decreased the number of files sended to client (but they will be obviously bigger)

Comment: Thanks I think there is a link on the angular.io also which gives a better idea.https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/webpack.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use "SystemJS Builder" (https://github.com/systemjs/builder) and integrate it into something like Gulp to make it part of your build process for bundles. You give it an entry point (your app) and it then looks at your dependency tree to build your bundle(s).

When your bundle is used, systemjs will import from your bundle instead of every little js file. When I tested with angular2, I had over 700 files downloaded in DEV and only 35 in PROD when using the bundle.